# We're unable to send the password reset email

Tags: magento-2.1, email

I'm using **Magento 2.1** When I try to reset my password by using forgot password link, I get following error.

> Error : We're unable to send the password reset email.

Comment: In local or server?

Comment: Have you checked your system/exception logs

Answer (score 2):

You will require to install SMTP module to send email in Magento2.Magento 2 default not providing this feature.

You can install below module and configure settings

https://github.com/magepal/magento2-gmail-smtp-app

After install put your email id and password in settings and send test mail.

[image]

if you still getting issue,check your log file and let me know.

**Note**: Install module with composer.

Thanks,

Comment: I already installed this module.

Comment: check updated answer.Install module with composer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to install any custom module to configure custom SMTP.

Magento now provides DotMailer module by default, which provides the option to configure sending emails using custom SMTP.

To do so, follow the below steps:

- Login to the admin panel.
- Go to **Stores** >> **Settings (Configuration)** section.
- Under **DOTMAILER** tab, click on **Transactional Emails** section.
- Under **DDG Transactional** section, set the value of **Enabled** field to Yes.
- Provide correct values for **Host**, **Username**, **Password**, and **Port**.
- Save the configuration by clicking Save Config button and refresh the Cache.

[image: dotmailer settings panel]

Please let me know if you find any problem.

Comment: In Magento version 2.1 I can't see DOTMAILER tab.

Answer (score 0):

Please look up the table *admin_user* on your database and try to change the password for the user name which you're trying to reset.

If you still not able to access the admin, please run the below commands:

```
    php bin/magento setup:upgrade
    php bin/magento setup:di:compile
    php bin/magento cache:flush
```

I hope this will help for you.

Answer (score 0):

Since at least the newest security patch in June 2019 Magneto 2(.1.18)'s forgotpassword.phtml customer module template has a form key like the one below.

Without the form key, the form will fail, which is likely if your theme includes a custom forgotpassword.phtml based off an earlier version of Magento.

getBlockHtml('formkey')?>